# pop-up box using jquery doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, javascript, jquery, popup

To be short, the problem manifests here:

http://mybgagent.com/offer_detailss.php?offers_id=4810

Clicking "Total Cost of Ownership" in Opera or Firefox brings out the pop-up window on top of the page as expected. However, in IE (tested in versions 6 and 8), it appears on the bottom of the page.

Here's the CSS and JS that I use.

http://mybgagent.com/tcocalc.css http://mybgagent.com/tcocalc.js

I think the problem's in the CSS, but I can't really tell where - I've never cared much for IE compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix is in your style sheet for the #tcocontainer div element, chnage:

```
position: fixed;
```

to:

```
position: absolute;
```

IE doesn't handle fixed positions very well. You'll lose the behavior where the popup stays in view even as the user scrolls the window, but usability shouldn't suffer. If you really want to keep the fixed position in other browsers then you can use conditional comments to create a separate style rule for IE only that has position: absolute;

```
<!--[if IE ]>
    <style> #tcocontainer { position: absolute; } </style>
<![endif]-->
```